# pyqtgraph histogram find and set colour automatically

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, pyqtgraph, colormap

I have a pyqtgraph imageitem with an associated histogram. I can change the colour of the image by selecting it from the histogram. What I want to do is save the name/number/something of this process so that I can later create the image and automatically load this colourmap using just this information.

How do I do this?

I can see the values of the colourmap in LUT but saving 512 x 3 values is a bit too much for me. I would really appreciate a better solution.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to do this. When I click on the colourmap I record the selection in the program and can then use this whenever I want.